# Storing water after reconstituting dried mushrooms

Tags: food-safety

I like to use dried mushrooms when I cook. I soak them in water for a while and then I use the mushrooms. Normally, I either pour the water down the drain or use it right away to give more flavor to rice.

Would it be safe to store that water in refrigerator to use for cooking rice another day? If so, how long can I keep it in the fridge? Are there any special precautions I should take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one day, I would think keeping it in the fridge is ok; use a covered container.

For more than one day, I'd freeze it;

Heck, I would freeze it from the start just in case I don't use it a day after.

Comment: And if you freeze it in an ice cube tray, you can easily use as much or as little as needed.